Upgraded Ubuntu and the error "Oh no! Something went wrong" appeared
After this error I tried with Ctrl+ Alt + F3 and then:
sudo apt update && sudo apt dist-upgrade 
sudo apt clean && sudo apt autoremove && sudo reboot

I couldn't make it work and tried some other stuff, but now I turn on my laptop and this appears:


DId you download and manually install Nvidia drivers? Can you boot into an older kernel?

No, I did not download nvidia drivers, maybe when I was trying to fix the problem I did something related to nvidia drivers... How can I try to boot into an older kernel? (i'm not a programmer or expert in this stuff). Thanks in advance!

login into the command line, and try running sudo apt install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop^ to restore the default GUI. Note that you need to include the ^

Thanks, just did it but did not work. It says “unmet dependencies. Try ‘apt —fix-broken install’ with no packages (or specify a solution)”
